# Python except block not running

Tags: python, block, tweepy, except

My goal is to retweet and favorite the very first tweet on a user’s timeline. If the very first tweet hasn’t been retweeted or fav, it retweets the tweet and fav, otherwise going to the except block and print "already retweeted" and sleep for 5 minutes.

**Here is my code:**

```
for i in iter(int, 1):

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='realdonaldtrump', include_rts=False, exclude_replies=True).items(1): 
    try:
        print('\nTweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name) 

        if not tweet.retweeted:
                    tweet.retweet() 
                    print('Retweeted the tweet')
        if not tweet.favorited:
                    tweet.favorite() 
                    print('Favorited the tweet')
        sleep(60)

    except:
        print('Already retweeted and favorited please be patient till next tweet')
        sleep(300)
```

But here the script never goes to the except block when the tweet is already retweet. I don't known why. Please explain how to solve this problem.

```
except:
            print('Already retweeted and favorited please be patient till next tweet')
            sleep(300)
```

**My logs:**

```
2020-08-04T16:06:14.608937+00:00 app[worker.1]: Tweet by: @realDonaldTrump
2020-08-04T16:06:14.785120+00:00 app[worker.1]: Retweeted the tweet
2020-08-04T16:06:15.013208+00:00 app[worker.1]: Favorited the tweet
2020-08-04T16:07:15.566250+00:00 app[worker.1]: Tweet by: @realDonaldTrump
2020-08-04T16:08:15.822568+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-08-04T16:08:15.822615+00:00 app[worker.1]: Tweet by: @realDonaldTrump
2020-08-04T16:09:16.229441+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-08-04T16:09:16.229453+00:00 app[worker.1]: Tweet by: @realDonaldTrump
```

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to use `else` not `except`?

Comment: Are you expecting tweet.retweet() or tweet. favorite() to throw an exception? Because you are not  raising any explicitly!! I think you are looking for is a if..elif..else block rather than a try..catch block..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `except` block only runs if the `try` block returns an error. If the `except` code never ran, then that means there is no error to catch from the `try`. If you remove the `try/except` error catching, you will probably find that their is no error given, this is why the `except` code never runs.

Try this code

```py
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='realdonaldtrump', include_rts=False, exclude_replies=True).items(1): 
    print('\nTweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name) 

    if not tweet.retweeted or not tweet.favorited:
        tweet.retweet() 
        print('Retweeted the tweet')

        tweet.favorite() 
        print('Favorited the tweet')
    else:
        print('Already retweeted and favorited please be patient till next tweet')
        sleep(300)

    sleep(60)
```

Comment: thanks bro its working ✌️✌️✌️ thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct